# How to select the same column from multiple table with almost same name in SQL?

Tags: sql

I'd like to select a 2 column from lot of table.

Exemple

```
Table_2017-01
id   name   value

Table_2017-02
id   name   value

Table_2017-03
id   name   value
```

etc...

My Query would be

```
SELECT name, value 
FROM Table_2017-01, Table_2017-02, Table_2017-03
```

But I'd like to know if something it's possible like

```
SELECT name, value FROM LIKE Table_%
```

I know this last query is not possible and it could be easier for me if a query exist for this problem as I can have a lot of table with just a part of the name different.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? In general you'd need dynamic SQL for this (the design is highly questionable however)

Comment: First, this is a bad database design. Instead of using multiple tables, use a single table and just add a column to indicate the relevant month.
Second, implicit joins are out of date by over 25 years now. You should always use explicit joins. Third, I think in this case you need union all, not join.

Answer (score 0):

To select mutiple columns with the same name you have to the table as prefix like:

```
SELECT `Table_2017-01.name`, `Table_2017-02.name`, `Table_2017-03.name` FROM Table_2017-01,`Table_2017-02, Table_2017-03
```

If you want them in one Column, use `Union`.

```
(SELECT `Table_2017-01.name` from Table_2017-01)
Union
(SELECT `Table_2017-02.name` from Table_2017-02)
```

Comment: You are assuming the OP is using MySql, but that's not indicated anywhere in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your database. Oracle f.e. has a data dictionary with all tables.
Because I know oracle better than others I use this for the example:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'Table_2017-%';
```

Now there are the following ways I sometimes use:

I build a list of selects and fire them into the database:

- via Excel (not explained here)
- via SQL

  SELECT 
    'SELECT '''||TABLE_NAME||''' TABLE_NAME, NAME, VALUE FROM '||
    TABLE_NAME
    ||' UNION '
  FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'Table_2017-%';

Now you can copy the result to your database (dont forget to delete the last "UNION")

- via program (python, Lazarus, c# .. whatever, same view is needed)

But pay attention: It is quick and dirty, the column names and types have to match.